# How to input images of different sizes into a CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of grayscale images that I want to use in a Convolutionnal Neural Network, for prediction purposes.
The images have a very wide range of sizes, and for multiple reasons, I don't want to resize or pad or crop them to get the same shape.
In terms of structure of the CNN, a solution is to add a GlobalMaxPooling2D or a GlobalAveragePooling layer as the
last step of the extraction part of the CNN, in order to get a single neuron per feature map, hence a 1D array that only
depends on the number of filters (i.e. is independent of the size of the input images).
Also, the first layer of the CNN should have as input: 'input_shape=(None,None,1)', and model.fit should use 'batch size=1'.

That's very fine, but I don't how to feed my CNN with images of different sizes, as I can't stack them into a single array structure.
I'v tried to put each individual image in a list of arrays, or in a numpy array with dtype= object format, but I always get an error when I run the 'model.fit' command. Depending on the input type I use, I get errors like: 'Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples' or 'Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)' or 'ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 235 y sizes: 50000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.').
I also used y_train as a 1D list or as an numpy array, or as a categorical variable, but it doesn't help.

I've seen this type of question several times, but I've never seen some code showing how to feed the CNN with inhomogeneous images 'in real'.
Any idea?

The basic code I use is as follows (keras with tensorflow):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(7,7), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(None,None,1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D(None,10))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
```

with

```
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), batch_size=1, epochs=10)
```

Comment: You certainly can't do it with TensorFlow, which compiles model with input shape fixation. PyTorch is more relaxed, it will probably work while 'batch size=1'.

Comment: That is not true, TF can handle different input shapes just fine. However you cannot have them in _the same batch_ and I would assume it's the same in Pytorch. The standard solution would be padding everything to the same shape, or resizing images.

Comment: Yes what @AlexeyBirukov said is not true, I have made variable input size CNNs using Keras, by using the (None, None, 3) input shape for color images. This works but I did not train with variable sized images, there are still issues within the same batch as there is the implicit assumption that all of them have the same shape (also a numpy limitation).

Comment: Hmm, indeed, didn't know it's possible.

    inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
    
    feature_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, )(inputs_1)
    
    model = keras.Model([inputs_1, ], [feature_1, ], )
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
                  
    model( np.zeros( (1,16,16,3) ) )
    
    model( np.zeros( (1,32,32,3) ) )